# How to parse and modify xml data using python lxml

Tags: python, xml, python-3.6, lxml

I need to modify the XML tag values using lxml (Author and Description) by parsing through xml files. below is the input file I am using and the output file I need. Below is the code I am using:

input xml file:

```
<Summary>  
<Author>ABC</Author>  
<Description>ABC DATA</Description>  
<Function>24</Function>  
</Summary>
```

Required output file:

```
<Summary>  
<Author>DEF</Author>  
<Description>DEF DATA</Description>  
<Function>24</Function>  
</Summary> 

from lxml import etree  
root = etree.parse(r"C:\Users\input\input.xml")  
    for elem in root.xpath('.//Author'): 
    elem.text = "DEF"  
    root.write("output.xml", pretty_print=True,xml_declaration=True,encoding="UTF-8")
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current code?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<root>
    <Summary>  
        <Author>ABC</Author>  
        <Description>ABC DATA</Description>  
        <Function>24</Function>  
    </Summary>
    <Summary>  
        <Author>ABC</Author>  
        <Description>ABC DATA</Description>  
        <Function>24</Function>  
    </Summary>
</root>'''

tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
for author in tree.findall('.//Summary/Author'):
    author.text = 'new author value goes here'
for desc in tree.findall('.//Summary/Description'):
    desc.text = 'new desc value goes here'

ET.dump(tree)
# call the line below if you need to save to a file
# tree.write(open('new_file.xml', 'w'))
```

output

```
<root>
    <Summary>  
        <Author>new author value goes here</Author>  
        <Description>new desc value goes here</Description>  
        <Function>24</Function>  
    </Summary>
    <Summary>  
        <Author>new author value goes here</Author>  
        <Description>new desc value goes here</Description>  
        <Function>24</Function>  
    </Summary>
</root>
```

Comment: tree = ET.parse(r"C:\Users\input.mxl")  
root = tree.getroot()  

for author in root.findall('./Summary/Author'):  
    author.text = "DEF"  
tree.write('output.mxl', xml_declaration=True, encoding="UTF-8")

Comment: I have tried the above code . But control is not getting into for loop

Comment: @ishkk467 Did you copy & paste the code and try to run it? See https://repl.it/repls/TomatoNutritiousSet for online (running) version of the same code.

Comment: yes and getting the same issue ..Control unable to go inside for loop.Do not know where did I done wrong.

Comment: Click the link in my previous comment. It points to an online python editor which contains the code. Hit 'Run' and see it in action. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking to replace each occurance of "ABC" with "DEF" but otherwise leave the text as-is, this should do it:

```
dat = [your input above]

nodes = ['Author','Description']
for node in nodes:
    for elem in root.xpath(f'.//{node}'): 
        elem.text = elem.text.replace("ABC","DEF")
```

The output is your desired output.